# Producing mesh plots in Plotly with non-square X,Y,Z arrays in Python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, visualization, mesh, surface

I am building a sphere with three square arrays, `x`, `y`, and `z`. The shape of each array is (100,100) (that is `x.shape = (100, 100)`), and I can plot the surface with Plotly:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

r = 1000
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:100j, 0:np.pi:100j]
x = np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)

# Plotting layout
titlecolor = 'white'
bgcolor = 'black'
noaxis = dict(showbackground=False, showgrid=False, showline=False, 
              showticklabels=False, ticks='', title='', zeroline=False)

layout = go.Layout(autosize=True,
         titlefont = dict(family='Courier New', color=titlecolor),
         showlegend = False,
         scene = dict(xaxis=noaxis, yaxis=noaxis, zaxis=noaxis,
                      aspectmode='auto'),
         paper_bgcolor = bgcolor,
         plot_bgcolor = bgcolor)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, opacity=0.2), layout=layout)
plot(fig, validate = False, auto_open=True)
```

which produces

[image]

But now, let's say I don't want to show the entire sphere -- instead, I want to remove points where Z > 0.8, and show *that* shape. I do this by flattening `x`, `y`, and `z`, finding indices in `z` where `z>0.8`, and removing those indices from all three arrays:

```
# Remove points where z > 0.8
x,y,z = [i.flatten() for i in [X,Y,Z]]
rmvidx = np.where(z>0.8)
x = [np.delete(x,j) for j in rmvidx][0]
y = [np.delete(y,j) for j in rmvidx][0]
z = [np.delete(z,j) for j in rmvidx][0]
# Add in new axis
x = x[:,np.newaxis]
y = y[:,np.newaxis]
z = z[:,np.newaxis]
```

Now, each array has shape (7900,1); furthermore, `np.sqrt(7900)=88.8819`, so the 1D arrays cannot be reshaped into square arrays without adding or further removing points.

I want to create a similar surface from these points. If I try to use the same plotting method (`go.Surface`), nothing is displayed, and `go.Mesh3d`:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, opacity=0.2), layout=layout)
```

also produces a blank image with no surface. How can I use Plotly to show a 3d surface for the 1D arrays, similar to what I was able to produce for the sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems that you are using an old Plotly version. A simpler code that runs with any version released starting with 2020:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:100j, 0:np.pi:100j]
x = np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)
axes_off=dict(xaxis_visible=False, yaxis_visible=False, zaxis_visible=False)
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale="matter_r"))
fig.update_scenes(dict(**axes_off))
fig.show()
```

Instead of deleting some elements, just invalidate them setting on `np.nan`:

```
z[np.where(z>0.8)]=np.nan
fignew=go.Figure(go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale="matter_r"))
fignew.update_scenes(dict(**axes_off))
fignew.update_layout(width=500, height=500, font_size=11)
```

[image]

Second: to install a new ploly version use the command:

```
pip install plotly --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to surfaces defined by x, y z of shape(m, n), with m≠ n, both go.Surface, and go.Mesh3d work as in the case with the shape(m, m):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos
u = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u,v)
x = u*cos(v)
y = u*sin(v)
z = u**2
#x, y z are of shape  (100, 50)
fig = go.Figure(go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z))
```

or as a triangulated surface:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
u = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u,v) #u, v have shape(100, 50)
u1,v1 = u.flatten(),v.flatten()
points2D=np.vstack([u1,v1]).T
x = u1*cos(v1)
y = u1*sin(v1)
z = u1**2
tri= Delaunay(points2D)
i, j, k = tri.simplices.T
fig = go.Figure(go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, i=i, j=j, k=k,intensity=z))
```

If you have in mind another case, please give a minimal example.

Comment: Per your request, I've updated my original question with a minimal example.